# 287 is not a valid cURL handle resource

Tags: php, curl, nginx

Recently switched server from Apache2 to nginx/1.4.6 with PHP5-FPM and every time i try to run curl i get:

```
curl_error(): 287 is not a valid cURL handle resource
```

Curl is installed (running "curl url" in CLI works fine), the PHP module is also installed.

My code:

```
$file_name_with_full_path = $composed_filename;
$post = array('image'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I searched around and found several answers, none of them worked. Found one that said that cURL might have removed the handle before it was done, how can i test that?

Comment: Unrelated FYI -- the `@filename` API for cURL is deprecated. You should use the [CURLFile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class.

Comment: How do you print curl error? might it be after closing curl handle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [curl_file_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php) function. Try this

```
$file = curl_file_create('fullpath/to/image.jpg','image/jpeg','the_image');
$data = array('the_image' => $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

When handling XML I use `is_resource`:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(is_resource($ch)){
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $responseBody = substr($response, $header_size);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $responseBody;
}
else{
    return $response;
}
```